# Need help in coping buffer using memcpy

Tags: c, memcpy

in the following code when i use `fwrite` its giving correct o/p. While `memcpy` is not working.

```
typedef struct
{
  char *p1;
  char *p2;
} node;
char s[] = "hello";
char t[] =" there";
node t1, t2;
char str;
FILE op_f;

t1.p1 = malloc(sizeof(strlen(s));
t1.p2 = malloc(sizeof(strlen(s));

t2.p1 = malloc(sizeof(strlen(s));
t2.p2 = malloc(sizeof(strlen(s));

t1.p1 = s;
t1.p2 = t;
copy(&t1,&t2);

str = malloc(sizeof(strlen(s) + strlen(t));
/* gives o/p hello there */
fwrite(t2.p1,1,strlen(s),op_f);
fwrite(t2.p1,2,strlen(s),op_f);

/* gives o/p there */
memcpy(str,t2.p1,strlen(s));
memcpy(str,t2.p2,strlen(s));
```

Is there any way to copy buffer to str ??

PS: above code is just for reference not the actual code

Comment: Remember: you need to "malloc(sizeof(strlen(s)+1);"  Don't forget the null byte ;)

Comment: ya got it but still str is overwriting

Comment: `char str;` should probably be `char *str;` (you want a pointer to `char`s not just a single `char`)

Comment: Essentially, everything in this code is wrong. Every single statement contains errors or relies on erroneous assumptions.

Comment: You probably shouldn't post 'code for reference' that you haven't actually compiled and run. I doubt that the `fwrite` calls in your code actually produce the output "hello there", because you pass the same pointer `t2.p1` each time.

Comment: what did `copy()` do?  I see some unpleasant ellipsis and memory leak in your code :p

Comment: @James: his files writes work because of overlapping bugs (notice the second call has the element size at 2), whats works is, he never opened a file to write to as osgx pointed out.

Comment: @Necrolis: how does passing the same pointer `t2.p1` to `fwrite` first write 'hello', and then write 'there'? It would just write the same content twice, wouldn't it? Anyway, there are so many things in this code which would fail, I was just picking one.

Comment: @james: the second call has an element size of two, so it'll write 10 bytes, which means its writing more than just the first string, basically, its just a bug hiding other bugs... I suppose with  this there is enough bugs for everyone to have one :p

Answer (score 2):

You should declare str as char array, not a single char:

```
char str[500];
```

when str is declared as array, the str is a pointer (to the first element of array). And in your code - str was a char, but not a pointer. Memcpy needs pointers as first and second arguments

Also, use malloc for strings without sizeof:

```
 t1.p2 = malloc(strlen(s)+1);
```

Also, fwrite is used incorrectly, because the `op_f` is not initialized with `fopen` like:

```
 op_f = fopen("filename.txt", "w");
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings stored in char arrays need one extra byte for a terminator. When computing the size you need to add 1 extra position:

```
t1.p1 = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
```

This code

```
t1.p1 = s;
```

doesn't copy the text from `s` to `p1`, but sets `p1` to point to the same string as `s`.

This part

```
str = malloc(strlen(s) + strlen(t));
```

doesn't work because str is a single `char` and not a `char*`. You could try

```
char* str = malloc(strlen(s) + strlen(t) + 1);
```

If you really intend this to be tagged C++, you should consider using `std::string` instead. It handles all of these details.

Comment: Get rid of the friggin’ `sizeof`, it’s hurting me!

Comment: I looked at the end of the mallocs, for the missing +1. Didn't see the bad start, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed you use 'char str' instead of 'char *str', so the result of malloc (which is a pointer to string) it not correctly stored in the variable.

Also, when you malloc, you need to calculate the size the following way:  strlen(s) + strlen(t) + 1. The extra byte is for the terminating NULL character. And you don't need to use sizeof there. The finally statement will look like:

```
str = malloc(strlen(s) + strlen(t) + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

firstly, you should be using `strcpy` when working with strings (if they are null terminated), as your code currently has a bug which is hidden by the fact 'hello' and 'there' are the same length, to fix it you should be doing (same applies to the `malloc` calls):

```
fwrite(t2.p1,sizeof(char),strlen(t2.p1),op_f);
fwrite(t2.p2,sizeof(char),strlen(t2.p2),op_f); //was also a bug here, you used p1 instead of p2 and the size of each element should have been 1

/* gives o/p there */
memcpy(str,t2.p1,strlen(t2.p1));
memcpy(str,t2.p2,strlen(t2.p2));
```

Your real problem originates because `memcpy` doesn't increment pointers, hence you should be doing:

```
strcpy(str,t2.p1);
strcat(str,t2.p2);
```

or if you really want to use memcpy:

```
memcpy(str,t2.p1,strlen(t2.p1));
memcpy(str + strlen(t2.p1) - 1,t2.p2,strlen(t2.p2));
```

finally, your `malloc`'s return pointers, not a `char`, so `str` should be a `char*`.

Comment: Thank all , Necrolis , ur rpost was helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
/* These are static.  You SHOULD NOT write to either s or t! */
char s[] = "hello";
char t[] =" there";

typedef struct
{
  char *p1;
  char *p2;
} node;
node t1, t2;

/* I think you wanted "*str" here... */
char *str;

/* You definitely want "length of string + 1" here */
t1.p1 = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
strcpy (t1.p1, s);
...
/* strcpy() and strcat() might be applicable here */
/* strncpy() and strncpy() might be even better - it depends... */
str = malloc(strlen(s)+1 + strlen(t)+1);
strcpy (str, s);
strcat (str, t);
```

Comment: It's fine to write to `s` and `t`  if you no longer want them to contain "hello" and "there" - as long as you don't exceed the size of the arrays (six chars each, including the null terminator).

Comment: No it's not fine - some platforms will store "hello\0" and "there\0" in read-only memory.

Comment: the literals maybe, but the arrays `s` and `t` are modifiable copies of the literals.